# Delete the first line of the file

Tags: php, csv, export

Im having a problem of exporting my csv. Yes it can export but when it exported the colmun name is included. How can i remove the first row (column name) after i exported?

Tried looking for other solution yet it doesnt fit on my program

```
<?php
//include database configuration file
include 'config2.php';

//get records from database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM maternalproblem ");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "maternalproblem" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

    //create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

    //set column headers
    $fields = array('MPID', 'district_id', 'barangay_id', 'PID', 'tuberculosis', 'sakit','diyabetes','hika','bisyo');
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

    //output each row of the data, format =line as csv and write to file pointer
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

        $lineData = array($row['MPID'], $row['district_id'], $row['barangay_id'], $row['PID'], $row['tuberculosis'],$row['sakit'],$row['diyabetes'],$row['hika'],$row['bisyo']);
        df.to_csv($filename , header=False);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }

    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

    //set headers to download file rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);
}
exit;

?>
```

I just need to export the data and not with the column name. Thank you

Comment: fileds needs to be empty

Comment: thanks man it worked

Comment: you're welcome, Im women

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be simpler to just not put the column titles out into the file

So remove these lines

```
//set column headers
$fields = array('MPID', 'district_id', 'barangay_id', 'PID', 'tuberculosis', 'sakit','diyabetes','hika','bisyo');
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);
```